# Complex numbers, sum of two squared absolute values

Tags: analysis, complex-numbers

In school we learned this equation:
$ |A|^2 + |B|^2 = \frac 12 (|A + B|^2 + |A-B|^2)$ for complex numbers A and B.
I tried to understand this but it makes no sense to me at all. Would be nice if anyone could show me why this equation is true. Edit: I tried the following:
$A := a + bi,B := c + di$
$\frac 12 (|A + B|^2 + |A-B|^2) = \frac 12 (|a + bi + c + di|^2 + |a + bi - c - di|^2 = \frac 12 ((a+c)^2 + (b+d)^2 + (a-c)^2 + (b-d)^2) = \frac 12 ((a^2 +2ac +c^2) +(b^2+2bd+d^2)+(a^2-2ac+c^2)+(b^2-2bd+d^2)) = \frac 12 (2a^2 +2b^2 +2c^2 +2d^2) = a^2 + b^2 +c^2 + d^2 = |A|^2 + |B|^2$

is that correct?

Comment: Have you tried just computing both sides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting $$A=a+bi,B=c+di$$ then we get
$$|A|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$
$$|B|=\sqrt{c^2+d^2}$$ and
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(|A+B|\right)^2+\left(|A-B|\right)^2\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(|a+c+i(d+c)|)\right)^2+\left(|a-c+(b-d)i|^2\right)\right)$$
can you finish?
and we get $$a^2+c^2+2ac+c^2+d^2+2cd+a^2+c^2-2ac+b^2+d^2-2bd$$

Comment: I edited my question are my equations correct?

Comment: which equations do you mean?

Comment: I tried to solve it with your hint I added my try to the question.

Comment: you have mad a mistake, $$(a-c)^2=a^2+c^2-2ac$$ etc

Comment: Isn't that what I wrote? I wrote $(a−c)^2 = a^2 - 2ac +c^2 $

Comment: ok i have misread this sorry

Comment: it is $$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$$ and so the left-hand side

Comment: Thanks for this hint I got it now.

Comment: that is nice that you could solve your problem!!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Algebraic derivation**:

$$\frac{1}{2}(|A+B|^2+|A-B|^2)=\frac{1}{2}((A+B)\overline{(A+B)}+(A-B)\overline{(A-B)})=\frac{1}{2}((A+B)(\overline{A}+\overline{B})+(A-B)(\overline{A}-\overline{B}))=\frac{1}{2}(A\overline{A}+A\overline{B}+B\overline{A}+B\overline{B}+A\overline{A}-A\overline{B}-B\overline{A}+B\overline{B})=\frac{1}{2}(2A\overline{A}+2B\overline{B})=|A|^2+|B|^2$$

**Geometric derivation**: In the complex plane, draw a parallelogram $OAXB$ with one corner $O$ at $0$, the other two corners adjacent to $O$ at complex numbers $A$ and $B$ (and a final corner, diagonally opposite to $O$, at $X$). Recall that the modulo of a complex number is the length of the line connecting $0$ to that number. Now, notice that the length of the segment $AB$ is $|A-B|$ and the length of the segment $OX$ is $|A+B|$. Thus, the given formula is reduced to a geometrical theorem: *The sum of squares of the diagonals of a parallelogram is twice the sum of its sides*. This can be proven easily e.g. using cosine theorem on the triangles $OAX$ and $OAB$ to calculate the squared diagonals.

Answer (score 0):

Algebraically:

$A = a + bi$ and $B = c + di$ then

$|A| =  \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$

$|B| = \sqrt{c^2 + d^2}$

$A+B = (a+c) + (b+d)i$

$A-B = (a-c) + (b-d)i$.

$|A+B| = \sqrt {(a+b)^2 + (c+d)^2} = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 +c^2 + d^2 + 2(ab+cd)}$

$|A-B| = \sqrt{(a-b)^2 + (c-d)^2} = \sqrt{a^2+b^2 +c^2 + d^2- 2(ab+cd)}$

So

$|A|^2 = a^2 + b^2$

$|B|^2 = c^2 + d^2$

$|A+B|^2 = a^2 + b^2+c^2 + d^2 + 2(ab+cd)$

$|A-B|^2 = a^2 + b^2 +c^2 + d^2- 2(ab + cd)$

So $|A|^2 +|B|^2 = a^2 + b^2 +c^2 +d^2=$

$\frac 12*([a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2] + [a^2 + b^2 + c^2 +d^2])=$

$\frac 12*([a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + 2(ab+cd)] + [a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 - 2(ab+cd)]) =$

$\frac 12*(|A+B|^2 + |A-B|^2)$.

Note:  This is true for real numbers as well as strictly complex numbers:  $|x+y|^2 + |x-y|^2 = (x+y)^2 + (x-y)^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2 + x^2 -2xy +y^2 = 2(x^2 + y^2)= 2(|x|^2 + |y|^2)$.

Geometrically:

[image]

$|A+B|$ and $|A-B|$ are the lengths of two sides of a parallelagram.

$2|A|$ and $2|B|$ are the two diagonals of a parallelagram.

I believe there is theorem that if $s_1$, $s_2$,$s_3$ $s_4$ and $d_1$ and $d_2$ are the sides and diagonals of a parallelagram then $s_1^2 + s_2^2+s_3^2 + s_4^2 = d_1^2 + d_2^2$

So if $s_1 =s_3= |A+B|; s_2 =s_4= |A-B|; d_1 = 2|A|$ and $d_2 = 2|B|$ so have:

$2|A+B|^2 + 2|A-B|^2 = 4|A|^2 + 4|B|^2$ so

$|A|^2 + |B|^2 =\frac 12 (|A+B|^2 + |A-B|^2)$